# resolution of icon used via NSAttributedText

Tags: ios, ios7, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I am using an icon in a NSAttributedString via the following:

```
  NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
  textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notes-18w_18h.png"];
  NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
  [headerAS replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([headerAS length], 0) withString:@" "];
  [headerAS replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([headerAS length], 0) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];
```

It looks like their is some pixelation but I'm not 100% sure as this is the first time I've used an icon via NSAttributedString. It looks like this:

[image]

and the original icon looks like this:

[image]

Does this look ok? Or is there something I should be doing to my icon to improve the resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have a retina version of the icon also in the bundle. @2x

Comment: @timpone if you think this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as answer for reference and benefit of other people visiting this question.

Comment: I have retina and it is still pixelated.